# "Could not find the Main class" when opening a .jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, jar

When I try to open a .jar file by double-clicking it I get this message that "Could not find the Main Class", however it works when opening it with the command line.

I've been looking for a solution for some days, I found a lot of people asking the same questions, some of the answers I found suggest that the main class is not declared in the manifest.mf, however I checked it and it is declared, here is my manifest.mf

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.4
Created-By: 1.7.0_13-b20 (Oracle Corporation)
Class-Path: 
Main-Class: my_pack.Mainprog
[empty line]
[empty line]
```

I tried to run the jar that NetBeans builds, also with the fat jar plugin for eclipse and always get the same error.

Comment: Are you using windows?

Comment: Is the MANIFEST.MF file in `META-INF` ?

Comment: Is the class in the `jar` under `/my_pack/Mainprog`?

Comment: I am using windows, the manifest is in the meta-inf, and the class is under my_pack, the name of the main class is MainProg

Comment: When you say it works from the command line, are you running `java -jar JAR_FILE`?

Comment: Yes, I'm useing java -jar and it works

Comment: Have you ever run a runnable jar from your system before?

Comment: You say your main class is called MainProg (with a capital P) and in your manifest you have a lower case p.

Comment: oh, sorry my mistake, I meant Mainprog

Comment: Now that you say it, this .jar worked before but only on my computer, I tried in other computers and didn't work, and when trying to find the solution it just stopped working on my computer too.

Comment: Check the Java version if you are using a different PC to the one it was compiled on.  If you compile on a Java 7 compiler and try to run it on a Java 6 JRE it will throw this error

Comment: I'm not trying it on other computers until it works at least on the computer it was compiled.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is: 
Create a dummy project in your Netbeans and export it as a runnable jar. Then take your manifest and the dummy-project manifest and compare it.

Manifests are really a pain in the code. They need to be absolutely correct formatted. Take care on trailing whitespaces, missing/additional empty rows etc...

Maybe check the Java Version, you are using. Make sure, that your command line uses the same one, like setup in your environment variables. Maybe there are doubled declarations...

Which java.exe is associated with *.jar files in windows explorer? Try exactly THIS java.exe to run your jar from the CLI. Same issue then?

Good luck!

Comment: This manifest was created by netbeans, also I checked with another projects I made and some .jar files that I downloaded and checked it and it appears to be in correct format, also those .jar files that I downloaded work, so I think something is wrong with the manifest but I'm sure exactly what...